# Any FREE 3D Carousel control available?

Tags: wpf

Is there free 3d carousel control available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [this one](http://iltc.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/wpf-elliptical-layout-control-3d/) (with [source code](http://ilovetocode.googlecode.com/files/EllipticalLayoutControl3DDemo_VS2008.zip)).

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but:
http://wpfcarousel.codeplex.com/
Also free and open source.